# Unable to start pipenv with python 3.7

Tags: python, django, pipenv

I am following the examples in DjangoForBeginners by William S. Vincent and attempted to start a virtual environment in python 3.7 for django==2.7 but it seems that only Python 3.6 is required for starting the pipenv.

```sh
Jamess-MacBook-Pro:ch04 otomes$ pipenv install django==2.1
Warning: Your Pipfile requires python_version 3.6, but you are using None (/Users/otomes/.local/share/v/o/bin/python).
  $ pipenv --rm and rebuilding the virtual environment may resolve the issue.
  $ pipenv check will surely fail.
Installing django==2.1…
Adding django to Pipfile's [packages]…
✔ Installation Succeeded 
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (e222e2)…
An error occurred while installing django==2.1 --hash=sha256:7f246078d5a546f63c28fc03ce71f4d7a23677ce42109219c24c9ffb28416137 --hash=sha256:ea50d85709708621d956187c6b61d9f9ce155007b496dd914fdb35db8d790aec! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing pytz==2019.1 --hash=sha256:303879e36b721603cc54604edcac9d20401bdbe31e1e4fdee5b9f98d5d31dfda --hash=sha256:d747dd3d23d77ef44c6a3526e274af6efeb0a6f1afd5a69ba4d5be4098c8e141! Will try again.
     ▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉ 2/2 — 00:00:00
Installing initially failed dependencies…
  ☤  ▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉ 2/2 — 00:00:00
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/cli/command.py", line 254, in install
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       editable_packages=state.installstate.editables,
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 1992, in do_install
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       skip_lock=skip_lock,
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 1253, in do_init
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       pypi_mirror=pypi_mirror,
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 862, in do_install_dependencies
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       _cleanup_procs(procs, False, failed_deps_queue, retry=False)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 681, in _cleanup_procs
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       raise exceptions.InstallError(c.dep.name, extra=err_lines)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: []
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: ['dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../.Python', '  Referenced from: /Users/otomes/.local/share/virtualenvs/otomes-cBliFOGJ/bin/python3.6', '  Reason: image not found']
ERROR: ERROR: Package installation failed...
```

I just need to know how I can reinstall my pipenv.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The virtualenv that was created by Pipenv is broken; it could be that the Python version it referenced was uninstalled or its location was moved.

Tell pipenv to remove it:

```
pipenv --rm
```

A new virtualenv will be created for you when you then run `pipenv install` again.

Comment: Okay, it seems like it worked. I typed .                                                                       ```pipenv --rm``` 
and then reinstalled it by using  ```pipenv --python path/to/python. ```
Thank you so much!